# jira.create_sprint() returns JiraError HTTP 500 No Content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: python, python-jira

Using python and jira==3.0.1 I receive the following error when attempting to create a sprint.

```
JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 500 url: https://issues.redhat.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprint/10875
    text: No content to map to Object due to end of input
```

My code snippet follows:

```
jira.create_sprint(name=sprint,
                    startDate=start_dttm,
                    endDate=end_start_dttm,
                    board_id=10875
                    )
```

And I've tried with `board_id=10875` where I obtained the id from https://jira.somwhere.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=10875 and with `board_id="PROJECT_KEY"`. Both return the same error.

Looking for some assistance to get past this error.

Thanks!

Comment: I will add that `jira.sprints(10875)` works, returning a ResultList of all sprints contained within that board_id.  The sprints appear correct so I know I have the right board_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per response received from the github issue submitted, the following code is required: `options={"agile_rest_path": GreenHopperResource.AGILE_BASE_REST_PATH}`

My working code is as follows:

```
from jira.resources import GreenHopperResource

jira = JIRA(server="https://issues.example.com", 
            basic_auth=(os.environ.get('user'), os.environ.get('password')),
            options={"agile_rest_path": GreenHopperResource.AGILE_BASE_REST_PATH},
)

jira.create_sprint(name=sprint,
                    startDate=start_dttm,
                    endDate=end_start_dttm,
                    board_id="<board_id>"
                    )
```